# dynamically assigning an event

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am dynamically creating a GroupBox and trying to assign the MouseLeftButtonDown event to it to perform some action when the user left-clicks on it. This is what I've tried:

```
public MyClass()
{
    tagGroupBox.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(tagGroupBox_MouseLeftButtonDown);  //generates error: "tagGroupBox_MouseLeftButtonDown does not exist in the current context"
}

private void tagGroupBox__MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Left click event triggered");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are __ (double underscores) in handler method.

```
void tagGroupBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
        g.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(g_MouseLeftButtonUp);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(g);
    }

    void g_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```